# Have Apache to treat .exe as .php script. (Apache/2.4.10 -PHP 5.6.22-0+deb8u1 - Debian)

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, mime-types

I'd like to put in place a php logging script inside an .exe file (which is a plain text file anyways, to log additional things not shown up in apache logs, whos accessing for example /joomla/ecard.exe and further processing of malicious access attempts) - and no i don't run a joomla there :) ). The logging/processing part is no problem, but Apache always treats the .exe as octet stream and thus firefox is downloading the .exe instead of executing the php code inside it.

I repeat: I don't want to execute an exe (what would require a windows host anyway and run through phps exec command) I'd like to have an exe treated as a php script.

I've already tried to modify the .htaccess file and change the Handler / Type of exes, but with no luck. Last test was like this:

`cat .htaccess
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .exe
AddType application/x-httpd-php .exe`

Any ideas? It could have something to do with the file magic / MIME-TYPE?

Comment: Rather than try to change how Apache handles the file through htaccess, why not simply use htaccess to redirect attempts to access that file to a file with a `.php` extension which does what you want.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you.

Nevertheless I'd like to know why apache doesn't let me overwrite its Handlers. Or is it really the MIME type.

Comment: Some of the servers we use need to have handlers controlled differently, try adding the following two lines into your htaccess; `AddHandler cgi-script .exe` and `SetEnv PHP_EXTENSION .exe`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated.